# Fourier Transform of $1/k^4$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, integration, mathematics

I am dealing with a higher derivative theory problem and I have to perform the following integral,

\begin{equation}
\int \dfrac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf r}}}{k^4}
\end{equation}
This is because i have to solve something like $(\nabla^2)^2f=K\delta^3({\bf r}).$

I know that if the exponent in the denominator was a 2, the result is the Coulomb potential $1/(4\pi r)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory), but I didn't found anything about a 4 in the denominator.
Does anybody know the result of this integral?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I though that too, and before posting this I posted in Mathematics. I had no answer in Mathematics and then came to physics and it did work out succesfully. I think physics is not a bad place because many theories come up with this kind of integrals, and there are nice physical interpretations (propagator) with that mathematical formulation.

Comment: Note for others: The post is no longer crossposted to [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

We can proceed exactly as in the case of the Coulomb potential i.e. Fourier transform of $1/k^{2}$. So, performing the same steps as in Coulomb case, we have

$ \begin{split}
\int \frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{e^{i\vec{k}.\vec{r}}}{k^{4}} &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dk}{k^{2}} \left[\frac{e^{ikr} - e^{-ikr}}{ikr} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi^{2}ir}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \frac{e^{ikr}}{k^{3}}
\end{split}
$

To perform the final integral, we can simplify as

$ \begin{split} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dk \frac{e^{ikr}}{k^{3}} = (\pi i)Res(\frac{e^{ikr}}{k^{3}}) = -\frac{\pi ir^{2}}{2} \end{split} $

Here, since the pole is on the contour we take only half its contribution when using the residue theorem. Using this we have finally,

$\begin{split}\int \frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{e^{i\vec{k}.\vec{r}}}{k^{4}} = - \frac{r}{8\pi} \end{split}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work out perfectly, the result makes much sense by dimensional analysis. Can you explain me with more detail the second equal sign in the first equation? The trick of splitting the integral in that way works for me in the case we had $e^{ikr}+e^{−ikr}$, because then $\int_0^\infty (e^{ikr}+e^{-ikr})dk=\int_0^\infty e^{ikr}dk+\int_0^\infty e^{-ikr}dk = \int_0^\infty e^{ikr}dk-\int_0^{-\infty} e^{ikr}dk =  \int_0^\infty e^{ikr}dk + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{ikr}dk = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikr}$ I'm missing something here. Can you explain the application of residue theorem too?

Comment: There is a $k^{3}$ term in the denominator which gives an extra minus sign under the change of variables from $k\rightarrow{-k}$.

Comment: That's absolutely true, my bad and thank you so much. The absence of the factor 2 in the residue integral is because there's only a semicircle contour, right?

Comment: It is because of the fact that the pole lies on the contour. You can check Arfken for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Could you explain how you are finding the residue? 

I am trying to do the same calculation by regularising the integral and starting with $\frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}}{k^4 + a^4}$ so I end up with Res($\frac{ke^{ikr}}{(k + j a)(k-j a)(k+ j^* a)(k- j^* a)}$) where $j^* = \sqrt{i}$